# How to include vertical lines in DiscretePlot?

Tags: plotting

There are several questions about *removing* the default vertical lines in a DiscretePlot, but my issue is that I *want* to show/emphasize the vertical lines in this DiscretePlot. By default they are not showing up. How can I control their appearance?

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** Use the option `BaseStyle` (or `PlotStyle` or `FillingStyle`  -- thanks: BrettChampion):

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}, 
 ExtentSize -> Full, BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thick]]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, use the option [`ExtentElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtentElementFunction.html):

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
  ExtentElementFunction -> 
   ({Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[{Darker @ Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"], Thick}], 
     ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##]} &)]
```

[image]

**3.** Yet another way: post-process to add `EdgeForm[..]` before `Rectangle`s:

```
 DiscretePlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}, ExtentSize -> Full] /. 
  r_Rectangle :> {Dynamic[EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], Thick}]],  r}
```

[image]

Comment: In addition to `BaseStyle`, you could also use `PlotStyle` or `FillingStyle` to set the `EdgeForm`.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}, ExtentSize -> Full] /. 
 Line[a_] :> Line[Partition[Flatten[a, 1], 2, 1]]
```

[image]

Or this?

```
DiscretePlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}, ExtentSize -> Full] /. 
 Line[a_] :> 
  Function[{p, q}, {EdgeForm[{JoinForm["Round"]}], FaceForm[], 
     Polygon[{p, q, Projection[q, {1, 0}], Projection[p, {1, 0}]}]}] @@@
    Partition[Flatten[a, 1], 2, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: the second one. thanks.