# ListPlot: FillingStyle option with EdgeForm directive

Tags: plotting, style

I would like to give my `ListPlot` a more bar-like appearance like seen in this question:

[How to include vertical lines in DiscretePlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250133/how-to-include-vertical-lines-in-discreteplot/250139#250139)

I tried:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4},
   Filling -> {1 -> Bottom},
   FillingStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.06], CapForm["Butt"], EdgeForm[Black]],
   Frame -> True,
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> False},
   PlotRangePadding -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}]
```

[image]

But obviously `FillingStyle` doesn't accept `EdgeForm` specifications.

Is there another way to surround the bars with a thin black line?

And a second question:

Is it possible to hide the `GridLines` behind the bars (overwrite `GridLines` with `FillingStyle`)?

Comment: See `Graphics->Options->Methods` in the docs for `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`.

Comment: Thank you, I added this option, but it doesn't help

Comment: Works for this toy example: `ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}
 , {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}
 , ContourStyle -> {{Thickness[0.02], Red}, {Thickness[0.02], Blue}}
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, White}, {Gray, White}}
 , ContourShading -> Automatic
 , Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
 ]` and certainly deserves a separate question.

Comment: FillingStyle does accept `EdgeForm` specifications, but they have no effect because the output from `ListPlot` has no polygons.  The "filling" is made with `Line` primitives using an explicit `Thickness` setting.

Comment: Similar to [31060](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31060/how-can-i-make-a-list-plot-with-bars).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pts = {1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4};

ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}, 
 Prolog -> First @ BarChart[pts, 
    ChartStyle -> Blend[{White, ColorData[97][1]}, .2], Axes -> False,
    BarSpacing -> Large, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect - and I can even create combinations like `ListPlot[{pts1, pts2},
 Joined -> {False, True}, 
 Prolog -> First@BarChart[pts1, ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]]`

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
c = 0;
pts = {1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4};
ListPlot[pts,
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Thick}], LightBlue, 
   Rectangle[{++c - 0.5, 0}, {c + 0.5, #}] & /@ pts}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6.01}, {-0.1, 6}}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Addendum**

With different styling:

```
c = 0;
pts = {1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4};
ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Thin}], LightBlue, 
   Rectangle[{++c - 0.4, 0}, {c + 0.4, #}] & /@ pts}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6.01}, {-0.1, 6}}]
```

[image]

Comment: It would be near to perfect with the following changes: (1) `Edgeform` `Thin` instead of `Thick`, (2) `Rectangle` width of `0.4` to get spaces between the bars and (3) `.../@ (pts - 0.1)`  inside `Epilog` to make the small points more visible.

Comment: Done, but why you do not make such small changes yourself?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is about `ListPlot` but the output is starting to resemble a `BarChart`. Can you perhaps use it in this particular instance?

```
pts = {1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4};

BarChart[pts
 , ChartStyle -> {Directive[
    EdgeForm[{Black, Thin}], LightBlue]
   }
 , BarSpacing -> Medium
 , GridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}
 , PlotRange -> {{0.5, 6.6}, {-0.3, 6.7}}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, Max@pts], None}
   , {Range@Length@pts, None}
   }
 , Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize@Large, Darker@Cyan
   , Point@Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #} &@pts]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in many cases I could use it, but in some cases I have to use `ListPlot`.  +1 anyway

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Or, given an answer for [`DiscretePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html), convert the [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) to a `DiscretePlot`.

```
DiscretePlot[{1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4}[[n]], {n, Length@data},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 ExtentSize -> 0.25, BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thickness[Medium]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[rectangleFilling]

rectangleFilling[w_ : 12, op_ : .8, ef_ : Automatic] := 
 ReplaceAll[
  GraphicsComplex[c_, p_] :> 
   GraphicsComplex[c, 
    p /. Line[{a_, b_}, ___] :> 
      Dynamic @ {Opacity[1], Blend[{CurrentValue["Color"], White}, op], 
        EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[2], 
          ef /. Automatic -> CurrentValue["Color"]}], 
        Rectangle[Offset[{-w, 0}, c[[b]]], Offset[{w, 0}, c[[a]]]]}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
rectangleFilling[]@
 ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4}, Filling -> Bottom, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}]
```

[image]

```
rectangleFilling[20]@
 ListPlot[MapIndexed[{{#2[[1]], #}} &]@{1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4}, 
  PlotStyle -> "Rainbow", Filling -> 2.5, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}]
```

[image]

Replace `Filling -> 2.5} above with` Filling -> {1 -> Top, 2 -> 5, 4 -> Bottom, 6 -> 2}` to get

[image]